# GPU Usage While Training LSTM Model Using Darts

Tags: time-series, gpu, lstm, pytorch-lightning, u8darts

I am currently using the Darts library to do some time series forecasting using an LSTM.

In my arguments I set the model to utilize my GPU and [the output from the dashboard during training shows that my GPU is indeed being used.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F1DM8.png)

Looking at the documentation as well confirms that what I am seeing means the GPU is being used for training. https://unit8co.github.io/darts/userguide/gpu_and_tpu_usage.html.

However, looking at my GPU in task manager it says that my GPU usage is at 0%. That does not make any sense to me? Does anyone know what goes on behind the scenes and might be able to explain why the GPU usage would be at 0% during training?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be that your GPU is under-used, e.g. because your CPU is not feeding it fast enough. Try playing with the `num_loader_workers` parameter, increasing the batch size, and reading the recommendations provided [here](https://unit8co.github.io/darts/userguide/torch_forecasting_models.html#performance-recommendations).

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I did some tweaking and did get some additional GPU usage after playing with the `num_loader_workers` param and increasing batch size.